# "DateTime.Now" - why does it return GMT?

Tags: datetime, asp.net-2.0, gmt

I am running on a Win2003 server, TimeZone set to (GMT -06:00) Central Time.  I am programming with VS.NET 2005, f/x 2.x.  When I execute the following code I do not get the expected results - but only when it is on the PROD server.  Any other machine **appears** to work correctly.

```
_response.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
```

Is there a setting hidden somewhere that can do this to .NET web apps?  I looked through all the configs I could find but did not see anything right off.

---

NOTE:  This is happening on all of our servers...

---

NOTE:  I tried using a date passed in to my page:

```
[parameter 3] (Date): Thu Nov 05 22:23:16 MST 2009  // Web client time
LastPlayed (Date): Fri Nov 06 05:23:16 MST 2009  // Simple boxing of value

public class FlashObject
{
    #region Declarations
    public DateTime LastPlayed;
    public List<PlayList> Characters;
    public List<PlayList> Variations;
    #endregion
}
```

The above object is simply hydrated like this:

```
internal static void GetPlayer(FlashObject flashObject, DateTime clientPlayTime)
```

Notice they are both in MST (Mountain Standard Time)!!    :(

Comment: Does changing the culture info (or loacle) make any difference?

Comment: Nope.  I've checked everything I can think of.  The TZ on the servers are set for Mountain time, the time is set correctly, the locale is set correctly, no overrides in all of our browsers, etc.

Comment: I had this very behavior on a Russian client's machine many moons ago. It turned out to be an issue with Windows itself; the copy of Windows was Russian and therefore any language or time other than Russian was simply impossible! No UI Cultures or changes to Windows made a blind bit of difference.  Unfortunately, this doesn't help you any. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I have changed my DateTime variables into DateTimeOffset variables.  I also changed the Flash/Flex code to pass in a TZ Name and Offset.  With this information I can track client times accurately.

```
private void SetUserInfo(DateTimeOffset ClientTime, int Offset)
{
    if (Offset != 0 && ClientTime.DateTime == ClientTime.UtcDateTime)
    {
        ClientTime = ClientTime.AddHours(Offset);
        _actionDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(ClientTime.DateTime, new TimeSpan(Offset, 0, 0));
    }
    else
        _actionDateTime = ClientTime;

    _actionUtcDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(_actionDateTime.DateTime.ToUniversalTime(), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
}
```

With the above bit of code I can now save client time as well as UTC time.

Comment: As anyone who deals with time in .NET applications should, so long as they're using .NET 3.5 or newer. Unfortunately, those still targeting older versions of the CLR are buggered.

Answer (score 0):

what is `_request`?

Internally, on the `HttpContext` object, reflector shows this code:

```
public DateTime get_Timestamp()
{
    return this._utcTimestamp.ToLocalTime();
}
```

Comment: _request is an object I defined in my app.  It is mainly a struct type object with further struct type objects and collections inside.  THere are no methods and it is intended just to carry well formed data around the app.